# WebAPI and Azure AD integration

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

After a lot of searching, most of the scenarios moves all the authentication to Azure AD and WebAPI just has to know how to read the token. (To achieve this we are using Azure AD middleware in OWIN pipeline). Also, this means that any client that wants resources from the WebAPI has to authenticate to Azure AD on their own (For example: adal.js for JS). Lets say my I want to keep user info within my WebAPI. I suppose I can easily just Create/Read users using some unique field in Azure AD JWT token and I do not need to worry about token validity or any other stuff about security since this middleware does that for me. Simply, I can just use it.

**And here comes the mystery that I can not understand.**

1. What if my WebAPI requires specific claims that Azure AD does not provide. For example authorization (permissions and so on) or even organizationId (in multitenant application).

Azure AD works as external identity provider, same as Google, Facebook and so on. But the difference is that most of user authentication logic lives in WebAPI (at least with the examples you can find). Client application receives a list of external providers a WebAPI supports and that is it. This gives an opportunity to introduce LOCAL AUTHORITY tokens with the claims WebAPI would need. But it kind of means that you start creating your own identity service within WebAPI, you also have to manage refresh tokens and so on.

2. Does it mean that the proper solution would be to start using IdentityServer that integrates variety of external providers and manages token creation with specific claims that my WebAPI would expect?

Comment: So you are looking at authorization. If the properties shared by the claims of auth provider is not good enough for you then you should do have a custom authorization. AD will only do authenticate and you will have an unique identifier for each user. You can have a separate database where you store custom user roles / personas which you can query based the unique identifier.

Comment: So you either have to adapt existing API to work with Azure AD tokens (if certain data is missing you will have to do an explicit call to database) or introduce IdentityServer which will authenticate against Azure AD and issue local authority token with the claims you need?